# Looking for a dataset: labeled soccer players images cropped from a fixed-view camera

Tags: data-request, images, machine-learning, sports

I am developing a method for soccer player detection and labeling in a field from a fixed-view camera. I wonder if there exist a dataset that contains several images for each player across different frames. The ideal dataset would have a few hundreds (if not thousands) images of only maximum a few dozen players from a top-view, with each image file name containing the name of the player. The image would be of course quite low-resolution, being originally cropped from a larger view of the football field.

Any idea if such or similar datasets exists? (I would like to avoid the tedious task of creating one myself)